# Numeric context in zsh array indexing

Tags: zsh

I have an array `schemes`, defined by

```
schemes=( a b c d e )
```

and want to pick a random element from it. My first attempt was

```
echo $schemes[1 + (RANDOM % $#schemes)]
```

This resulted in an *invalid subscript* error every time I run this (i.e. independent of the random number generated). I then changed the code to

```
((n=1 + (RANDOM % $#schemes)))
echo $schemes[n]
```

and it works fine. Why? After all, array indexing imposes the same kind of numeric context as `((....))` does, isn't it? So the two approaches should be equivalent.

Comment: It seems that it works either when the expression is in double quotes `echo "$schemes[1 + (RANDOM % $#schemes)]"` or no quotes and without spaces `echo $schemes[1+(RANDOM%$#schemes)]`. But to answer your question why it is like this, I have no clue.

Comment: Good point! Perhaps this is because word splitting in zsh occurs before parameter expansion, and hence before the subscripts are evaluated. However, I did not find anything in the man pages (should be in _zshparams_, which explains this.

Comment: @rowboat: Thanks. The link you provided really answers this!

Comment: @user1934428 Since your question got answered, can you please close the question?

Comment: I don't see how to do this in this case. Actually, the comment given by rowboat has the best explanation I got so far, so I tried to close it on the grounds that it is a duplicate of the question rowboat pointed out to me. But SO allows "close due to duplicate" only if the 'duplicate' appears within [so]. What else could I select as "closing reason"?

Comment: @user1934428 You don't need to literally close it per sé. What you can do is write an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: @MarlonRichert : Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information kindly provided by @rowboat:

It is a parsing problem. Within square brackets, only certain characters are allowed, and a space is not one of them. When the parser encounters the space, it doesn't look further but throws an invalid subscript error.

This applies only if array access is lazily written as `$schemes[...]`. If I write the offending line as

```
echo ${schemes[1 + (RANDOM % $#schemes)]}
```

the space is not an error anymore.